# How do I correctly write this array for my javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have run into this problem again and now really need to  know how to correctly write this array.

I have a drop-box that, based on the value selected, will display a particular field-set(s) via the ID of the field-set.

In some cases, two different values from the drop-box may call the same field-sets. So for example, if I choose **banners**, several field-sets will be displayed, if I choose **Homepage Updates**, the same field-sets would be displayed. So I want my array to basically be>> if the value selected in project type drop-box equals **Banners** or **Homepage Updates**, show the specified field-sets. The problem is, **only** the first option works. In this case Banners. When I select Homepage Updates, nothing is displayed.

Does anyone know who to write this array correctly? I have a ton of types that I have to code and the array is the clearest way to write it, but I can't get past this hurdle.  Help please. A portion of the array is below.

```
var projectTypes = new Array (
  {id : '660' , value:('Banners' ||'Homepage Updates')},
  {id : '659' , value:('Banners' || 'Homepage Updates')},
  {id : '661' , value:'Banners'}, 
  {id : '662' , value:'Banners'},   
  {id : '663' , value:'Banners'}, 
  {id : '668' , value:'Redirect'}, 
  {id : '229' , value:'Affiliates'},
  {id : '236' , value:'Affiliates'},
  {id : '242' , value:'Affiliates'},
  {id : '250' , value:'Affiliates'},
  {id : '251' , value:'Resources'},
  {id : '375' , value:'Resources'},
  {id : '376' , value:'Resources'},
  {id : '377' , value:'Ads'},
  {id : '237' , value:'Ads'}
);
```

Comment: what are u trying to achieve with value:('Banners' ||'Homepage Updates')???

Comment: If "Banners" selected, show fieldsets 1, 2, 3 : if "Homepage Updates" selected show fieldsets 1,2,3.  The selection are from a dropdown box, so there are tons of options with various fieldsets that will display or not.

Comment: @user1176783 did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your expression `('Banners' ||'Homepage Updates')` will always be evaluated to `'Banners'`.
The logical operator **OR** ( written as `||`) is evaluated as :

```
boolean OR boolean
```

Since the first expression's argument is a String that is not empty, it is automatically converted to a `true` value (because of the automatic type-conversion.

In your case, I suggest You use an array of possible values to for your objects.
This way, you can choose the appropriate one:

```
var projectTypes = new Array (
  {id : '660' , value: ['Banners', 'Homepage Updates']},
  {id : '659' , value: ['Banners', 'Homepage Updates']},
  {id : '661' , values: ['Banners']}, 
  {id : '662' , values: ['Banners']},   
  {id : '663' , values: ['Banners']}, 
  {id : '668' , values: ['Redirect']}, 
  {id : '229' , values: ['Affiliates']},
  {id : '236' , values: ['Affiliates']},
  {id : '242' , values: ['Affiliates']},
  {id : '250' , values: ['Affiliates']},
  {id : '251' , values: ['Resources']},
  {id : '375' , values: ['Resources']},
  {id : '376' , values: ['Resources']},
  {id : '377' , values: ['Ads']},
  {id : '237' , values: ['Ads']}
);
```

If I understand correctly and you want to access some ids based on a value, you could organize your objects like this :

```
var projectTypes = {
    'Banners' : [660, 659, 661, 662, 663],
    'Homepage Updates' : [660, 659],
    'Redirect' : [668], 
    'Affiliates' : [229, 236, 242, 250],
    'Resources' : [251, 375, 376],
    'Ads' : [237, 377]
};
```

Comment: Trying 1st option, not workingfunction projectTypeChange()
{ 
var project_type = document.getElementById(projectType_Field_Id).value;
refreshSections(project_type);
} 

function refreshSections(selectedType) { 
for (var i = 0; i < projectTypes.length; i++) 
{
if (projectTypes[i].value == selectedType) 
{
document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = '';
} 
else 
{
document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = 'none';
}
}
}

Comment: Restating : Trying 1st option, not working. Where u have value: [Resources] should it have ending brace ex: value: [Resources]},

Comment: this is the onChange function that will display the different sections:   function projectTypeChange()
{ 
var project_type = document.getElementById(projectType_Field_Id).value;
refreshSections(project_type);
} 

function refreshSections(selectedType) { 
for (var i = 0; i < projectTypes.length; i++) 
{
if (projectTypes[i].value == selectedType) 
{
document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = '';
} 
else 
{
document.getElementById("section-"+ projectTypes[i].id).style.display = 'none';
}
}
}

Comment: And THANKS for explaining why it's not working to begin with.  I could not for the life of me figure out why that simple [OR] operator in the array was/is not working.